# Could not grant admin consent. Your organization does not have a subscription (or service principal) for the following API(s): Power BI Service

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have activated Power BI Pro License in my tenant.
I have Azure AD with Same Account.
I have added following Permissions.
[In the screenshot, I have added these Power BI Service Permissions which need admin access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCCxK.png)

My account has full admin privileges on Azure and Power BI.
[AdminPortal from Power BI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAKaJ.png)

Now, when I try to Grant Permission to Power BI API, I am getting following error.
"Could not grant admin consent. Your organization does not have a subscription (or service principal) for the following API(s): Power BI Service"

[Power BI - Grant Permission Error in Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWfYu.png)
Please suggest me, what changes I need to do? How to check if my tenant have active Power BI Subscription or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try linking your O365 subscription with your Azure subscription. It's possible that you're trying to access certain objects from an account that is unable to gain access to them. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory

Sign in using an account that:

1. Has an Owner role assignment for the subscription. For information about how to assign the Owner role, see Manage access to Azure resources using RBAC and the Azure portal.
2. Exists in both the current directory that's associated with the subscription and in the new directory that's where you want to associate the subscription going forward.

Answer (score 3):

Just want to add my 2 cents.

I faced this exact same issue when i was trying to register a web api and a client app in my Azure AD b2c tenant. And this error was thrown when i was trying to grant admin consent to the client app for the permissions exposed by web api.

In my case, issue was, my user was not the global administrator. Hence, the organization was somehow not having full access to my web api. To resolve this, I asked global administrator to create the web api registration and then this error went away.

Hope this will help someone. Thanks.